# How to make an Agent work in the system session?

Tags: macos, daemon, agent

I'm trying to a background program that need to connect to window server, which is not allowed in a daemon. But may job is quite appropriate to be done in [System] session which daemons act.

I have tried to set session of the Agent.(Aqua by default)

```
LimitLoadToSessionType: System
```

But it didn't work.. Is it wrong? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

May be [LoginWindow] + [Aqua] could match the right session. But between the two session, the program need to be shutdown and relaunched.